# Speed Up Zsh Loading Time in tmux

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh, tmux

Like many users, I'm experiencing slow load up times with my shell on macOS.
I've seen many questions about this topic, and I'm using a suggested workaround, which is setting the terminal emulator (iTerm2 in my case) to launch a non-standard shell using the command `/usr/local/bin/zsh`.

The problem is that this doesn't work when using tmux, opening a new session/window/pane still takes a few seconds.
I've already cleared the ASL logs (using `sudo rm /private/var/log/asl/*.asl`), and I don't think that the problem is in my `.zshrc` since the problem doesn't happen when launching iTerm2, and I've tried setting the default shell in tmux to the non-standard shell, either by putting the following command in my `.tmux.conf`: `set-option -g default-shell /usr/local/bin/zsh`, or by running `export SHELL="/usr/local/bin/zsh"` before opening tmux, and it still doesn't work even though I made sure the `$SHELL` variable was set correctly after launching tmux.

I'd appreciate any help.